# How to add 'private' python module to Google Datalab

Tags: google-cloud-datalab

I'm experimenting with the promising Google Cloud Datalab. In the past I've created some handy python classes and functions that I'd like to use in the GCD-notebooks but I don't know how to add my code.

Anybody any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is, on second thought, obvious:

```
%%bash
pip install git+http://myawsomepythonmodule.git
```

Comment: Awesome! That said, any idea why doesn't use primary Python env?  Datalab use virtual env?