# How to import user-written custom modules in google datalab?

Tags: google-cloud-datalab

I am new to Google cloud and datalab. I struggled to get it up and running. I was wondering how I could just import user-written .py files within datalab notebook.

I tried using "pip install git+~~". It installs, but it seems like it is installing in the wrong directory or something. I was not able to import it.

Please help me out.

Btw, I wonder how I could "pip install git+~~" for private repo. Notebook isn't interactive. I tried echo userid | echo password | pip install git+~

Thank you!

Comment: Not sure if this helps you at all: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33174293/adding-python-libraries-to-google-datalab-environment

Comment: This might help as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33165443/how-to-add-private-python-module-to-google-datalab?rq=1

Comment: @kayleeFrye_onDeck Thank you for the reply. I have already checked them out. That's how I tried the thing I mentioned. I am asking more details on the second posts, how I would import it once installed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the python package is created correctly, the import should work after installing the python package.

To install a package from Github (using the `xrld` package as an example), run either

```
!pip install https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd/archive/master.zip
import xlrd
```

or

```
!pip install git+http://github.com/python-excel/xlrd.git
import xlrd
```

I ran through the process of creating a [minimal python package](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/minimal.html) and was able to import it successfully in Google Cloud Datalab with:

```
import funniest
print funniest.joke()
```

After installing it with:

```
!cd funniest && pip install .
```

You can check the install location by running the following code:

```
>> funniest.__file__
'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/funniest/__init__.pyc'
```

Could you try also try creating a minimal python package and see if that works? You may be able to spot a subtle the difference between your package and the minimal package.